# How to create read-only bind mount in fully managed Cloud Run instance?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, debian, mount, google-cloud-run

How can I create a read-only, bind-mount in a fully managed Cloud Run instance? I'm looking to mount a folder inside the container's filesytem to another location in the same container's filesystem.  Is this possible?

[This](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#can-i-mount-storage-volumes-or-disks-on-cloud-run) unofficial FAQ indicates that mounting additional volumes is not supported, but it says nothing about bind-mounting a folder (internally) to a new location inside the Cloud Run container.

(Note: to be clear, I'm not trying to interface with the host or the host filesystem in any way.)

Answer (score 0):

Bind mounts are not supported by Google Cloud Run.

This feature mounts a file or directory from the "host machine" into a container. For a managed service this should not be possible (should not be allowed). Since you have no control over the host managing the container, you cannot specify a file or directory to mount.

If your goal is to create/mount a directory where you can retrieve information to maintain container state, take a look at Cloud Storage or one of the Google Databases (Cloud SQL / Datastore).

[Update: Added some links]

[Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract)

[Cloud Run FAQ](http://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq)

[Awesome Cloud Run](http://github.com/steren/awesome-cloudrun)

Comment: I'm actually hoping to mount a directory that's inside the container to another location inside the container, not a directory from the "host machine". I suppose this is not possible either, though. Is there a reference in the documentation about the lack of support for this?

Comment: Cloud Run does not support this. Regarding mounting a folder from another container, the only entry point you have is HTTP on $PORT (8080). If you are trying to run two containers inside the same Cloud Run service, you cannot do that either. Google does not document what you cannot do. It does with what you can do. I will update my answer with some links for you to review.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to do that. However, `bind mount` is not supported as mentioned in Ahmet's document. Since it is not supported, there is no document that I am aware of that specifies limitations of mounting volumes. You don't have access to a Docker host to interface with. A Cloud Run container runs on Knative with support from Istio. Cloud Run is a managed service, anything that you want to do with the host is prevented for security/management/common-sense reasons.